# What exactly is a true value of a parameter?

Tags: statistics, estimation

I am currently studying the properties of the Maximum Likelihood Estimator. One of these properties being the asymptotic normality, I found the following equation:

$$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta} - \theta_{0}) \rightarrow N(0, {I(\theta_{0})}^{-1}) \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$

where $\hat{\theta}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$, $I(\theta_{0})^{-1}$ is the Fisher information and $\theta_{0}$ is the 'true value of the parameter $\theta$'. However, it is not explained exactly what that means. Also, why should this 'true value' be in the formula? Would it not suffice to just use $\theta$ instead of $\theta_{0}$? I hope someone can clarify this for me.

Comment: Maybe you should read this first <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator> If there are specific questions left, you can post them.

Comment: To me it is still not entirely clear what is the difference between $\theta$ from $\theta_{0}$ in this case. $\theta$ is just a parameter of the distribution/density, so how does the 'true value' $\theta_{0}$ differ from $\theta$?

Comment: The distribution has a parameter whose true value $\theta_0$ is not known, f.e. the mean. You estimate the unknown value of the mean f.e. by the mean of a sample $\hat{\theta}$. The mean of a sample will never be equal to the true mean (if we consider f.e. the normal distribution), but if the sample size $n$ goes to $\infty$, it will approach it.

Comment: Here $\theta$ is the parameter in generic sense, while $\theta_0$ is the value of this parameter in the population of interest.